# observer not working on the stock sources selection in magento 2

Tags: magento2.3

When i select **stock sources** then my observer(catalog_product_import_bunch_save_after) is not working but when i import by products entity type then this observer is working. how can get data at the time of stock sources selection on the observer.
Please help me i am waiting for your responses.
Magento ver. 2.3.5-p1

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**catalog_product_import_bunch_save_after** event will be triggered when you're importing the products, but if you are importing the stocks and source so use the below events. (give a try)

**stock_sources_save_after**

**stock_sources_import_bunch_save_after**

Comment: Thanks Sathya,
For share these, i have checked these but not working for me if any other solution then please provide.